# How to create a mechanical vibration?

Tags: oscillator, generator, piezo, mechanical

I need to create a system which will make vibrate horizontally a plastic tube of diameter 4cm, of height 3cm, which axis is vertical, and whose weight is 11g. The frequency should be modifiable between 1Hz and 1kHz, and the amplitude should be roughly between 0.5mm and 3mm. The amplitude don't need to be precise. Does someone knows a way to produce such a mechanical vibration source ? What would be the orders of magnitude of the intensity/voltage of the generator ? Thanks !

Comment: Use a solenoid..

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us some effort so we know how to help.

Comment: How accurate does the frequency need to be?

Comment: A loudspeaker voice-coil could handle the *frequency* range, but to get 3 mm peak-to-peak amplitude flexion in a 4 cm plastic tube at 1 kHz would require a fair amount of  power -- tens or hundreds of watts, without knowing the modulus of elasticity of the plastic.

Comment: if f changes 3 decades at constant power, then so will amplitude, so did you want to be a little precise ? than a 6:1 range?  3/0.5mm? that's like no bass and full treble

Comment: Motor + cam follower.

Comment: You added a Piezo tag -- is that a requirement for your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would go purely mechanical.

This is my 10 seconds though design: a stepper motor with a cog but with sinusoidal serrated edge. That drives a lever, the pivot position of which determines the amplitude, the end drives your tube.

Answer (score 0):

Do a search online for a vibration generator. It is basically a loudspeaker coil and magnet design, but without the speaker cone and with a shaft attached for connecting to your experiment. You will need a sine wave signal generator and an audio amplifier.

The vibration generators are available from science education suppliers. Probably quite expensive though. Used one on eBay perhaps.